# What is the region of instability of a reduced equation of state?

Tags: thermodynamics

### What is the region of instability of a reduced equation of state?

I'm asked to give the region of instability given a reduced equation of state,
$$\ln\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{\widetilde{p}}{\widetilde{T}}}\right)=1-\ln(\sqrt{2\widetilde{v}-1})-\dfrac{1}{\widetilde{T}\widetilde{v}}$$
for $\widetilde{T}=1/2$, where $\widetilde{p}=p/p_c$, $\widetilde{v}=v/v_c$, and $\widetilde{T}=T/T_c$.

But I can't find a definition or a way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Maxwell construction.

Maxwell construction is a method of finding region of instability when you have an isotherm, on which the pressure increases with increasing of volume. This is not possible because it is nonsense. To find the whole region of instability you need to draw a line on the graph making sure, that what region above your line and below it has the same surface.
[image: Example of maxwell construction for Van der Waals equation]

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you graph the pressure as a function of volume. For an ideal gas you'll get something like:

[image: Ideal gas]

So as you reduce the volume, i.e. compress the gas, the pressure rises smoothly. However for a real, interacting gas, you'll get a curve more like this:

[image: Real gas]

The equation of state predicts that as you compress the gas the pressure will rise to a maximum then fall before rising again. What is actually happening is that the gas is liquifying. As you compress the gas the pressure rises until you reach the point where the blue dashed line starts. At that point further compression just causes liquid to form and the pressure stays constant. The system tracks along the blue line until at the left end of the line all the gas has turned to liquid and the pressure starts rising again.

The phrase *region of instability* isn't a precisely defined term, so I can't be 100% sure what your professor means by it. However it seems likely that this means the gas liquid coexistance region i.e. the region I've marked as *two phase* on the diagram.

So you just need to take your equation of state, draw the PV curve and see what it looks like.